# Bibtex entries do not show

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I've just started using using bibtex and encountered some issues. Unfortunately some of my entries do not show up and I can't figure out why.

Here my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,numbers=enddot]{scrartcl}



\usepackage[  backend=bibtex,
style=authoryear-icomp,
bibstyle=authoryear,
sorting=nty,
natbib=true,
url=false, 
doi=true,
eprint=false,
ibidtracker=false,
bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\bibliography{literaturverzeichnis} 
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}

\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\parentexttrack}[1]{%
\begingroup
\blx@blxinit
\blx@setsfcodes
\blx@bibopenparen#1\blx@bibcloseparen
\endgroup}

\AtEveryCite{%
  \let\parentext=\parentexttrack%
   \let\bibopenparen=\bibopenbracket%
   \let\bibcloseparen=\bibclosebracket}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[type=article,heading=subbibliography,title={Artikel}]
\printbibliography[type=techreport,heading=subbibliography,title={Technical    Reports}]
\printbibliography[type=conference,heading=subbibliography,title={Conference Collections}]
\end{document}
```

And here my bibtex file:

```
@ARTICLE {simple,
author  = "Maria Rodriguez Moreno, Juan Ignacio Pena",
title   = "Systemic risk measures: The simpler the better?",
journal = "Journal of Banking \& Finance",
year    = "2013",
volume  = "37",
pages   = "1817-1831"
 }
 @ARTICLE {covar,
author  = "Tobias Adrian, Markus K. Brunnemeier",
title   = "CoVar",
journal = "NBER Working Series",
year    = "2011",
note    = "Working Paper"
}
@CONFERENCE {bankforinternationalsettlements,
author    = "Bank for International Settlements",
title     = "Proceedings of a joint conference organised by the BIS and the Bank of Korea in Seoul on 17–18 January 2011",
booktitle = "Macroprudential regulation and policy",
year      = "2011",
volume    = "60"
}
@ARTICLE {covarmgarch,
author  = "Giulio Girardi, A. Tolga Erguen",
 title   = "Systemic risk measurement: Multivariate GARCH estimation of CoVaR",
journal = "Journal of Banking \& Finance",
year    = "2013",
volume  = "37",
pages   = "3169-3180"
}

@TECHREPORT {globalriskreport,
author = "World Economic Forum",
title  = "Global Risk Report",
year   = "2010"
}
```

For some reason the articles show in my bibliography, while the tech-report and the conference collection do not.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no such type as `@conference` (maybe you want `@proceedings` or `@inproccedings`), and the type `@techreport` is automatically aliased to `@report`. So you will have to use `\printbibliography[type=report,heading=subbibliography,title={Technical    Reports}]` for your `@techreport` and find a proper type for `@conference`.

Comment: Note that names have to be separated by `and`, so you need `author  = {Maria Rodriguez Moreno and Juan Ignacio Pena},` and the like. Names of corporations and institutions in the `author` or `editor` field need to be protected by double braces: `editor    = {{Bank for International Settlements}},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such type as `@conference`. You probably want to use `@proceedings` for `bankforinternationalsettlements`.

The type `@techreport` is automatically aliased to `@report`. So you will have to use

```
\printbibliography[type=report,heading=subbibliography,title={Technical Reports}]
```

for your `@techreport`.

Note that names have to be separated by `and`, so you need

```
author = {Maria Rodriguez Moreno and Juan Ignacio Pena}
```

and the like. Names of corporations and institutions in the `author` or `editor` field need to be protected by double braces

```
editor = {{Bank for International Settlements}},
```